# ATI Proprietary Driver Over/Underscan setting ignored after reboot

Tags: drivers, 12.10, proprietary

I installed the proprietary driver (fglrx-updates) on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit for my graphics card (ATI Radeon HD 7570). I am using two displays, one connected with DVI, one with HDMI. I set the desktop to be expanded to both screens and disabled the under scan for the HDMI screen, which is always for some reason enabled on HDMI screens.

Now the issue. Everything was fine until I restarted my computer. After reboot, the screen connected with HDMI cable had the black borders again, meaning that the under scan is again enabled. I checked the ATI CCC, and under scan was disabled. However, moving the slider to enable under scan and then back to zero fixed the issue -- temporarily. The same issue is repeated every time I restart my computer. The settings remains the same, but the computer seems to ignore it.

Any ideas how I could solve the issue?

Answer (score 7):

My dear friend Google helped me out with this. Slightly modifying the command given [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2023309) made the under scan behave like it should.

Here's the command that solved the issue:

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0
```

Answer (score 3):

Before doing:

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0
```

I also had to do a:

```
aticonfig --initial
```

I know, it's kinda obvious, and the error message tells you to - just thought I'd add that here in case someone is similarly concerned because it doesn't work right away.

Answer (score 1):

**Permanent Fix:**
The Catalyst Control Center (GUI) seems to have more than a few problems saving certain user settings and this solution helped me fix one of the more annoying side-effects of using the fglrx proprietary driver in conjunction with an HDMI monitor connection. I ran into a "permission denied' warning when attempting `aticonfig --initial` so I performed a slight modification to first step:

Open Terminal, then enter the following commands-->

First: (note: I had to use 'sudo')

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Then:

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0
```

---

**Additional Temporary Fix:**
There is also a hardware/peripheral-side quick fix which depends on the monitor's built-in settings menu. Unfortunately this is a temporary fix which must be done after each system boot, but at least it will get your desktop looking normal-sized while you work on the permanent solution above.

- Once you have logged into your desktop--> Bring up your monitor's built-in settings menu and look for "Input Select" (or some variation thereof). Depending on your monitor's menu, try to manually re-select HDMI **or** let it re-scan for connected input. With my Acer 23" for example, I press the MENU button then the INPUT button    and the monitor automatically re-selects HDMI after scanning for all possible choices, but now it displays with the correct resolution scaling.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0
```

You can scale the picture using this command using values 0-9 if it overscans after this setting, just use a value 1-9, like:

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,5
```

This is what my computer uses, this way the scaling is done on card and maintains pixel ratios.

(The value is actually the position of the slider in acccle control panel.)