# Amd driver problems!

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, graphics, resolution

Yesterday i installed the amd driver on my lubuntu 12.10 following this guide http://m.itworld.com/software/306225/install-amd-catalyst-1210-driver-ubuntu-1210?mm_ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3DInstall%2Bamd%2Bdrivers%2Bin%2Bubuntu      , after rebooting my pc, the screen resolution went low! And minecraft crashes each time i open it! Please help! I cannot change my screen resolution too as only one option is availalable!

Comment: Another unfortunate Catalyst user... Could you give us more specification on you ATI card? And your computer? Also, few words from me... Don't install Catalyst drivers if your games are working and movies run smoothly (I use `Gnome Player` and they work fine there). I have been trying several Catalyst drivers from 12.4 till 12.11 and none seem to work (my card is ATI Radeon HD 7290).

Answer (score 0):

try with this guide

[Ubuntu Quantal Installation Guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219044/ati-proprietary-driver-over-underscan-setting-ignored-after-reboot)

And check the section - **Using Ubuntu-supplied fglrx/Catalyst** - Work fine with my HD7850 and kernel 3.7.0-7 .

***Note:*** I had two minimal issues but the solution is here:

- [ATI Proprietary Driver Over/Underscan setting ignored after
  reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219044/ati-proprietary-driver-over-underscan-setting-ignored-after-reboot).
- [How to remove the “AMD Testing use only” watermark?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206558/how-to-remove-the-amd-testing-use-only-watermark)